# Why prolongational instead of cadential progression

Tags: classical-music, functional-harmony

I have some questions regarding Mozarts piano sonata K. 283.

[image]

According to [Hauser](http://elliotthauser.com/openmusictheory/sentence.html), "these four measures prolong tonic. Measures two and three are contrapuntal chords that are surrounded by the tonic".

My questions are

- what is meant with "contrapuntal chord"?
- why is the T-D-T progression not regarded as "cadential" in the sense of Caplin, Analyzing classical form, p. 14?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Caplin, ultimately following the philosophy of Heinrich Schenker, a cadence in the Classical style requires a root-position V chord. The chord in the third measure is a V7, but because of the F♯ in the bass it is in first inversion, which destroys the sense of cadence and instead just prolongs tonic.

You can think of a contrapuntal chord as any harmony that prolongs another harmony. In the progression I–V<sup>6</sup>–I, the V<sup>6</sup> isn't a true dominant (since it isn't root position), prolongs tonic, and thus is a contrapuntal chord. In the progression I–IV–V–I, however, V *is* in root position, thus is a functional dominant, and so the IV and V here are not contrapuntal chords.

By the way, there is a new version of *Open Music Theory* available [here](https://viva.pressbooks.pub/openmusictheory/).

Comment: I see, though I must say that the passage has some cadential feeling. But probably "cadence" is not only defined by chord progression, but also rhythmically and structurally.

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald ‘But probably "cadence" is not only defined by chord progression, but also rhythmically and structurally.’ Absolutely. There are many V chords followed by I chords in the classical literature that we do not hear as cadences because they are clearly not punctuation, pauses, or structural points. At the same time, there are clearly audible cadences in the post-classical literature where there is no V (or IV) chord nearby. Anyone still wondering about this might listen to unpitched percussion pieces and note they have cadences and structure despite having no harmonic content.

Answer (score 2):

Hauser feels that the 2nd inversion dominant in bar 2 and the 1st inversion in bar 3 are insufficient to properly establish a functional dominant, they merely decorate the tonic. Having D in the bass in bar 3 would make a structural difference.

Even if there was a root position dominant, I'd be wary of defining this passage as a cadence.  If we called cadence every time V - I occurred in this style of music, we'd be doing it every couple of bars!

But there's no 'right answer' to this sort of thing.  We've recognized what's happening musically.  That a dominant chord can be established lightly with an inversion or strongly with a root position.  And that a transitory I -V - I may or may not deserve labeling as a cadence.   Good!

Answer (score 0):

One more consideration is that some texts suggest that a cadence requires a predominant-dominant-tonic pattern. Ratman's book describes a pattern of 4-7-1 in some voice as necessary for a cadence.

The rhythmic and structural location also matters. In the Folia pattern, i-V-i-VII-III-VII-i-V-i, I would call the first V-i and the VII-III as non-cadential and the final v-i as cadential. Once I tried replacing the penultimate tonic with an Ab7 or an Augmented Sixth. It works. However, I did find some Spanish Folias from the 1500s doing the same thing. Some others wrote i-V-i-iv-VII-III-VII-VI-V-i which seems like a tonal adumbration.

The term "cadence" does seem to have changed meaning (or in use) over time. A V-I or V-i pattern, or a secondary equivalent, in a contrapuntal style, sounds different from using such a pattern at the end of phrases or periods.